# How do you edit a dynamic item in 7.0?

Tags: spotfire

I know this is pseudo off-topic for this forum, but I couldn't find any details anywhere.

After a recent upgrade from 6.5 to 7.0, I'm noticing that once you create a Dynamic Item > Calculated Value in the text area, it seems impossible to edit it.

In 6.5 you could create a Calculated Value in a text area, and then right click and format or edit that control. In 7.0 this is grayed our for dynamic items, but not for property controls. Does anyone have a work around to this? Specifically how to change:

- Font
- Font Size
- Font Attributes (Bold, Italic)
- Font Color
- etc...

Side note, I'm an admin so it can't be a rights / privileges issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that in 7.0 this functionality was removed via the right-click method, and only remains in the HTML editor.

1. Right Click on Text Area > Edit HTML
2. In the right pane, select the Dynamic Item
3. Select Edit at the bottom to edit the data, expression, etc
4. Select Format to edit the color, font, bold, etc...